# Scheme function to return random number

Tags: scheme

I am trying to use `random-integer` from `srfi-27` inside a function but it always returns the same number everytime I call it.

```
(use srfi-27)

(define get-n
  (random-integer 10))

(print get-n)
(print get-n)
(print (random-integer 10))
(print (random-integer 10))
(print (random-integer 10))
(print get-n)
(print get-n)
```

Output:

```
8
8
1
9
8
8
8
```

Can someone explain to me why this function always return to me the same number.

Additionally, how can I abstract the code for making the random number?

In the example I only ask for a number between 0 and 10 but in reality I want to do extra things to the number which is returned and I do not want to copy paste this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get-n` is not a function, it's just a variable that contains the result of a single call to `random-integer` when you assigned it. If you want it to get a new random number each time, you have to define a function, and call it as a function.

```
(define get-n
    (lambda() (random-integer 10)))

(print (get-n))
(print (get-n))
(print (get-n))
```

The above function definition syntax can be abbreviated as:

```
(define (get-n)
    (random-integer 10))
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but given what the OP is trying to do, probably better to use the shorthand, `(define (get-n) (random-integer 10))`.

Comment: For students, I think the `lambda` notation is better to help them understand how things work in Scheme.

Comment: I'm not saying to exclude the longhand version. Indeed, I agree it's important.

Comment: Also unless user wants the seed to be the same each time he runs his application he needs to do `(random-source-randomize! default-random-source)` first.